# Serve ReactJS app with JSON data pre-populated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I would like to serve up a ReactJS Single Page App from a nodeJS server and pass up some JSON data at the same time.

I have user credentials and some other user specific data that i would like pre-populated into my page and avoid making multiple round trips to the server.

How do i pass a JSON object to the client at request time and have it available to my React app

```
var path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}.`));
```

Comment: [The SSR guide in the Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/serverrendering#inject-initial-component-html-and-state) might give some insights even though you are not using Redux.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you add a `script` tag into your `index.html` file. Like below

```
<script>
  window._DATA_={ key: 'value', .....}
</script>
```

Now in your react application, use the key `window._DATA_` to get the data that you sent from the server. In this approach, the problem is that you **can't send dynamic data**.

To achieve that you may need to use the template libraries. For example `pug`, `nunjucks`, `ejs`, etc.

Below is the example of using `pug`.

Your express route will look like this.

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', data);
});


// End of your pug file looks like
...
...
script.
  var window._DATA_= !{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

If you want to add scripts files dynamically then you can use `html-webpack-pug-plugin`.

For more info
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-pug-plugin